# Installing package "icd9" in R from Github with Rtools ERROR

Tags: r, github

I'm trying to install package "icd9" from Github repository.

First I've installed devtools package.

Then

`devtools::install_github("jackwasey/icd9")`

After this line I have following report:

> ```
>    Downloading GitHub repo jackwasey/icd9@master
>    Installing icd9
>    "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save  \
>    --no-restore CMD INSTALL  \
>    "C:/Users/rubal/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpEHgKOa/devtools1fd4455976bc/jackwasey- 
>    icd9-ad36b5b"  \
>    --library="C:/Users/rubal/Documents/R/win-library/3.2" --install-tests 
>
>    * installing *source* package 'icd9' ...
>    Предупреждение: работающая команда 'sh ./configure.win' имеет статус 127
>    ERROR: configuration failed for package 'icd9'
>    * removing 'C:/Users/rubal/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/icd9' 
>
>    Error: Command failed (1)
> ```

What I do wrong? How could I install this package?

Comment: you installed devtools but did you load the library with library(devtools)?

Comment: Thank you! Checked this - `library(devtools)`. After this performed my command again. And stil this ERROR and nothing changed...

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/icd9/index.html Says there are several packages that it imports. Do you have all of them installed?

Comment: hum..it's working for me. Have you tried with CRAN? is your R older than R 3.1.0

Comment: Thank you, @42- ! That's the answer! All works now!

Comment: Thank you, @MLavoie ! Now it's work for me!

Answer (score 1):

Latecomer to this question, but as I'm the author of the said package, I should let you know that 'icd9' is deprecated. Now all ICD-9 and ICD-10 functions are contained in the much slicker, much faster [icd](https://cran.r-project.org/package=icd) package on CRAN.